# Customized tooltip for C3JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I have created a chart using C3.JS. It has bar graph with line graph like as shown below

[image]

The graph is working fine but I have a requirement that I need a line graph to be shown within the tooltip along with other data points.

The line graph is coming but the other data points are missing (x, data1, data2). In addition tooltip should come only on mouse click not mouse over also by default when the page loads the tooltip should appear for the last bar.

Current my tooltip shows only with the line graph like as shown below without the other data points(x, data1, data2)

[image]

But I expect my tooltip to appear like as shown below

[image]

My code is as given below

Can anyone please help me on this

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnh4h9s4/)

```
function generateGraph(tooltip, data1, data2) {
    // if the data is same as before don't regenrate the graph - this avoids flicker
   if (tooltip.data1 && 
       (tooltip.data1.name === data1.name) && (tooltip.data1.value === data1.value) && 
       (tooltip.data2.name === data2.name) && (tooltip.data2.value === data2.value))
       return;

    tooltip.data1 = data1;
    tooltip.data2 = data2;

    // remove the existing chart
    if (tooltip.chart) {
        tooltip.chart = tooltip.chart.destroy();
        tooltip.selectAll('*').remove();
    }

    // create new chart
    tooltip.chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: tooltip,
          padding: {
          right: 15
            },
        size: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        },
        data: {
        columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 160],
                ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25, 34]
            ]
        },
        tooltip: {
            show: false
          }
    });

    // creating a chart on an element sets its position attribute to relative
    // reset it to absolute (the tooltip was absolute originally) for proper positioning
    tooltip.style('position', 'absolute');
    tooltip.style('background-color', 'white');
}

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['x', 1000, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data1', 1000, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300], ],

            axes: {
                             'data1': 'y2'
                            },
            type: 'bar',
            types: {
              'data1': 'line'
            }
    },
    tooltip: {
        contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            // this creates a chart inside the tooltips
            var content = generateGraph(this.tooltip, d[0], d[1])
            // we don't return anything - see .html function below
            }
    }
});

// MONKEY PATCHING (MAY break if library updates change the code that sets tooltip content)
// we override the html function for the tooltip to not do anything (since we've already created the tooltip content inside it)
chart.internal.tooltip.html = function () {
    // this needs to return the tooltip - it's used for positioning the tooltip
    return chart.internal.tooltip;
}
```

Comment: why are you overriding `chart.internal.tooltip.html`? because of this you won't get any default tooltip info. the best way here would be to make a function which is returning an html. there you can specify your content and take even care of the `d[0].index == 4`

Comment: @Akoya Thanks for the reply, how can we return the html, it would  be great if u can share me an updated jsfiddle with the same

Comment: @Akoya Can you please help me on this

Comment: c3 is an abstraction of d3 meant to help you with graphs that are close to standard. For real customization I would always use pure d3.js as it is limitless and has much more to offer.

Comment: @AlexMan sorry, last week i was on vacation that's why i didn't saw your last comments. but looks like you already got a solution :)

Comment: @Akoya okay...do you have any best solutions.....

Comment: isn't the solution provided blackmiaool covering the critical points of your question? for the click behaviour you can try to use onmouseclick for some toggling option and manipulate the chart object... that's what i would try to do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Live Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/blackmiaool/y7Lhej4m/

Instead of overriding the `.html` function of tooltip, I use `contents` and css to customize the tooltip.

js:

```
contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
    generateGraph(this.tooltip, d[0], d[1]);
    var tip = this.tooltip[0][0].querySelector(".c3-tooltip");//find previous tooltip
    if (tip) {
        tip.parentElement.removeChild(tip);//remove it
    }
    return this.getTooltipContent.apply(this, arguments) + this.tooltip.html();//concat default tooltip and  customized one
}
```

css:

```
.c3-tooltip-container {
    max-height: none !important;
}

.c3-tooltip {
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.c3-tooltip tr {
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
}

.c3-tooltip td.name {
    border-left: none !important;
}

.c3-tooltip tr:first-child {
    display: none;
}

.c3-tooltip-container .c3-chart-line {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

[image]